# Pressing an ASP.NET button on an ASPX popup opens a new window. Why?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

I have a parent ASP.NET page, from which I'm opening a Popup window like this:

**Parent Page Code:**

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button2" OnClientClick="basicPopup();return false;" OnClick="Button1_Click"/></td>

function basicPopup() 
{
    var strReturn = window.showModalDialog("TaxReportInputsForm.aspx", person,'status:no;dialogWidth:450px;dialogHeight:110px;dialogHide:true;help:no;scroll:yes');

    if(strReturn.okpressed == true)
    {
        ....
    }
    else
    {
        ....
    }
}
```

Now, on the ASPX file that loads as a popup (i.e. `TaxReportInputsForm.aspx`), there are a few ASP.NET server-side buttons. When I click on a button, it opens yet another browser window, which has the same `TaxReportInputsForm.aspx` loaded in that too.

Why is this happening ? There is nothing in the code of the server-side button in the `TaxReportInputsForm.aspx`, which may suggest why its click triggers a third window to show.

And how can I prevent this ?

**Popup Page Code (`TaxReportInputsForm.aspx`):**

```
<asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" OnClick="Button2_Click" Text="Button" />

protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int f = 2;
}
```

Comment: In your `TaxReportInputsForm.aspx` page, make sure that you are not registering another window.showModalDialog somewhere (either in codebehing, or in the markup)

Comment: please check your <form ...> tag in .aspx file

Comment: @bastos.sergio, no I'm not explicitly calling any other page in the popup ...

Comment: @ayilmaz, what do I look for ? And which aspx are you referring to ?

Comment: you should create the pop up against a specific ID. like button1 has ID="Button1", so create a popup against this ID. in jQuery code